# Obtener ID de la carpeta en la que esta el fichero APPS SCRIPT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

GOOGLE DRIVE - APPS SCRIPT

1. Tengo un listado de ID de archivos
2. Los archivos están ubicados en carpetas diferentes.
3. No tengo los ID de las carpetas
   ¿Qué línea de código debo usar para obtener el ID de la carpeta en la que esta cada archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Con en método  [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=es-419#getParents())

```
function ObtenerIdyNameFolder() {

   idfile ='___ id file ___'
   folderparent = DriveApp.getFileById(idfile).getParents();

   var folder = folderparent.next();
   console.log( folder.getId(), folder.getName());

}
```